# Deploy the spring boot microservices on azure using pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-cloud-services

I deployed two different spring boot micro-service on azure cloud. With micro-service I also deployed eureka. When I register both the micro-service on eureka its done.My next task is to send the data from one micro-service to another. I am new to spring-boot so, on local system I perform same task and its working fine but on azure micro-services are not communicating with each other.
I am unable to establish a connection by using feign client and rest template as the IP and Hostname is dynamic. 
Please suggest what configuration do I need to make to achieve this task.

**What i have done**

I have configured eureka with below properties in its application properties:

```
spring.application.name=eureka.azurewebsites.net

eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.instance.hostname=eureka.azurewebsites.net
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Service1 in azure:

```
spring.application.name=service1.azurewebsites.net
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka.azurewebsites.net/eureka/
```

Service 2 in azure:

```
spring.application.name=service2.azurewebsites.net
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka.azurewebsites.net/eureka/
```

Now when i try to call rest api from service 1 to another service 2 get unknowhost exception.

Below is the code snippet:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Service2 {
       private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PLMBommsApplication.class);
       @Bean
       @LoadBalanced
       RestTemplate restTemplate() {
             return new RestTemplate();
       }
       @Autowired
       RestTemplate restTemplate;
       @RequestMapping(value = "/")
       public StringBuilder fromCall() throws URISyntaxException {
             StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
              URI uri = new URI("http://service1.azurewebsites.net/receiverPOST");
             MultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
             mvm.add("abc", "Hello Part");
             result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, mvm, String.class);
             response.append("successPost = " + result);
             response.append("\n");
             return response;
             }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
             SpringApplication.run(Service2.class, args);
       }
```

Comment: If you are able to share some of the code of what you are trying to do or what the errors are when you try to run it that will help people understand and provide relevant suggestions.

Comment: When you go to the Eureka dashboard does it show both services as being registered?

Comment: @ShawnClark Yes I can see both the service are being registered

Comment: Then you should be able to use Ribbon with Feign or RestTemplate to specify just the service name instead of the IP / hostname of the other service. Ribbon will do the lookup with Eureka to populate the URL with the correct information.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-ribbon

Again without seeing some of your configuration and how you are using things within your code I can't provide much more info.

Comment: @ShawnClark  I have edited my question for more details can you please cross check